# Vimeo OAuth 2 authentication

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-android

I am working on Vimeo OAuth authentication in my android application.
Here is the api link [Vimeo Authentication](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication)

But i am getting issue on pre Kitkat OS devices that Login button is not taking click on webview client.

If any one have any idea about this issue and how to resolve please help.

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide additional information about the problem? Such as what your OAuth2 callback url is and what devices it works on?

Comment: I think call back URL is only needed after login process is done. There is nothing wrong with the callback URL. I have two testing devices Nexus 5 with 6.0.0 OS version and samsung galaxy duos with OS version 4.2.2. On nexus it is working fine but on samsung it is not taking click on login button.
I have read Google has introduced Chromium support in web view with 4.4 (Kitkat) and newer OS here is the link [link](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview)
On chromium support browsers Vimeo authentication seems to work fine but i want to use Vimeo on pre kitkat devices.

Comment: Ohhhh, I misread. By "not taking click", you mean that the user can not click the login button at all in the kitkat webview?

Comment: on 'PRE KITKAT WEBVIEW' login is not taking click

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is still valid for you, but we recently released [vimeo-networking-java](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java) which should help with OAuth authentication. The specific instructions on how to get it working can be found [here in the README](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java#oauth-authorization-code-grant).

But the basic idea is that we provide you with a method to take care of the code grant redirect and it can be implemented with the following:

```
private void onLoginClick() {
     // Go To Web For Code Grant Auth
     String uri = VimeoClient.getInstance().getCodeGrantAuthorizationURI();
     Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
     startActivity(browserIntent);
}
```

If you follow the rest of the readme, it will cover how to get the redirect uri set up.